# Dynamic conditions of array for javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, dynamic, conditional-statements

```
const conditionalArray = [
  { name: "line", condition: ">=", value: 5 },
  { name: "revene", condition: "in", value: 6 },
];

const dataTofilter = [
  { line: 3, revene: 4, sale: 3, fridge: "lg" },
  { line: 6, revene: 3, sale: 2, fridge: "samsung" },
];
```

I have these 2 arrays one is having conditions ( many more can be there) and second is to filter

Final result should be `[{ line: 6, revene: 3, sale: 2, fridge: "samsung" }]`

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: @Behemoth Can you please let me know how to filter using conditional array

Comment: What is `{ name: "revene", condition: "in", value: 6 }` supposed to mean? `revene in 6` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Sebastian instead of 6 some string revene in (‘abc’)

Comment: Ah, okay, so `in: (a, b) => b.includes(a)` or similar as a function property in the approach below, right? The question still says `value: 6` instead of `value: "abc"` and numbers cannot be searched by contents.

Comment: Sebastian - It worked only for single value but if my a is somthing like this ‘abc,def’ then it din’t as abc and def are not proper strings

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of:

```js
const conditionalArray = [
  { name: "line", condition: ">=", value: 5 },
  { name: "revene", condition: "<", value: 6 },
];

const dataTofilter = [
  { line: 3, revene: 4, sale: 3, fridge: "lg" },
  { line: 6, revene: 3, sale: 2, fridge: "samsung" },
];

const conditions = {
  '<': (x, y) => x < y,
  '<=': (x, y) => x <= y,
  '>': (x, y) => x > y,
  '>=': (x, y) => x >= y,
};

const result = dataTofilter.filter(data => {
  for (const el of conditionalArray) {
    if (!conditions[el.condition](data[el.name], el.value)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow beautiful one!

Comment: @MikeM Yeah I know .Wow best answer .. Thanks  a ton !!

Comment: @MikeM Can you let me know if condition contains in operator how to make function

Comment: @Singla How does `in` relate to the `value`?

Comment: @MikeM can you help me here var searchQuery = {}; //or something specific like {name: 'Kitten Name',name: ‘cat’; var foundKittens = []; Kitten.find(searchQuery , function (err, kittens) { if (err) foundKittens = null } else { foundKittens = kittens } });

Comment: Find should return both if name is kitten or cat

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not a big fan of it. But I don't see another way as [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to make the `condition` work as an actual operator without doing plenty of manual checks. Also the following solution assumes that every item in `dataToFilter` has a corresponding item in `conditionalArray`.

```js
const conditionalArray = [
  { name: "line", condition: ">=", value: 5 },
  { name: "revene", condition: "<", value: 6 },
];

const dataTofilter = [
  { line: 3, revene: 4, sale: 3, fridge: "lg" },
  { line: 6, revene: 3, sale: 2, fridge: "samsung" },
];

const result = dataTofilter.filter((item, i) =>
  eval(
    `${item[conditionalArray[i].name]}${conditionalArray[i].condition}${
      conditionalArray[i].value
    }`
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I would advise you to avoid `eval`. Use `const operators = { "<"(a, b){ return a < b; }, ">="(a, b){ return a >= b; } };`, etc., then `return operators[conditionalArray[i].condition](conditionalArray[i].name, conditionalArray[i].value);`. Also, the question sounds like _all_ conditions should be applied to _all_ `dataToFilter` objects, not one-by-one, index-by-index.

Comment: Yes, I know it's no a brilliant idea to use `eval`. However it indeed makes it quite a lot simpler for that small problem. If it gets more serious I would, of course, also go with the manual case detection.

Comment: Go with [@MikeM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68822307/12834972)s solution then. It should be the accepted one for this post in my opinion. I misinterpreted your question a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
const newData = dataTofilter.filter((item) => {
   const passedConditions = [];
   conditionalArray.forEach((cond) => {
       switch(cond.condition){
           case ">":
              passedCondition.push(item[cond.name] > cond.value);
              break;
           case ..... //other conditional checks
       }
     }); //end forEach

     return Arrays.asList(passedCondition).contains(false) === false;
});
```

If you don't want to use `eval` you can do something like this.  We loop through all the data first and use `filter` to only return values that pass our conditional check.

We then loop trough the conditional array testing each condition on the single item and save the value to `passedConditions`. You will need to add the rest of the conditions.

Finally we return wether the `passedCondtions` array ***did not*** contain a `false` value.  This would mean we passed all the conditional checks.