# Dynamic evaluation of conditions not using Eval()

Tags: javascript, filter, dynamic, conditional-statements, evaluation

I need to be able to evaluate (True/False) some conditions not using Eval method. I came across this awesome technique which suits my needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68822307/9481833

Now I am trying to implement something like a Like operator and found the test function. Tried to amend the example as per the below but no joy:

```
const conditionalArray = [
  { name: "fridge", condition: "like", value: "sam" },
];

const dataTofilter = [
  { line: "Blah", revene: 3, sale: 2, fridge: "samsung" },
];

const conditions = {
  'like': (x, y) => x.test(/y/),
};

const result = dataTofilter.filter(data => {
  for (const el of conditionalArray) {
    if (!conditions[el.condition](data[el.name], el.value)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(result);
```

Error message is that 'test' is not a function. Perhaps I'll need to handle this case in the filter codeblock at the bottom and look for the 'like' operator and handle it there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Therefore you should use `match`. I also fixed your `like` function so it won't match `/y/` the literal but rather `y` the variable. Note: it needs escaping for RegExp.

```js
const conditionalArray = [{
  name: "fridge",
  condition: "like",
  value: "sam"
}, ];

const dataTofilter = [{
  line: "Blah",
  revene: 3,
  sale: 2,
  fridge: "samsung"
}, ];

const conditions = {
  'like': (x, y) => x.match(new RegExp(y)),
};

const result = dataTofilter.filter(data => {
  for (const el of conditionalArray) {
    if (!conditions[el.condition](data[el.name], el.value)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great thanks but out of interest why is 'test' not a possibility ? I looked to it as match is slower from reading I have done here and elsewhere

Comment: `test()` is not a method of a `String` (as `x` is) but rather of `RegExp`

Comment: Ok thanks again. Learning a lot. By that logic, match is not a method of a string either, so why doesn't 'x.test(new RegExp(y))' work ?

Comment: It is of [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) sorry for ambiguity

Comment: No worries thanks. All I need is a Boolean response to the condition being met. Is 'match' the only/fastest method to achieve this ?

Comment: `String.prototype.includes` is faster https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript